# Moving legacy lib folder into a more modern structure

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-6

I have several modules on a `lib` folder on Rails 3:

```
/lib
/lib/library
/lib/library/library.rb #This imports with requires, file_a, file_b, etc...
/lib/library/file_a.rb
/lib/library/file_b.rb
/lib/library/file_c.rb
```

I'm trying to determine the best way for this to work using Rails 6. I've read a little on Zeitwerk.

My conclusion is that I need to move this lib into `app/lib` for autoloading.

However, my library still does not load. Any advice or pointers on how I can import this library on a migrated Rails server?

Comment: Does this code really belong in `/app` or can it be extracted into a separate gem?

Comment: It could exists as a separate gem. But it's only used on our codebase for now and I really don't think it'll live elsewhere, so I don't think its worth the trouble of exporting into a separate gem.

Answer (score 1):

You can move your files to the following structure

```sh
/app/lib
/app/lib/library
/app/lib/library/library.rb # you can remove this file if it only contains requires
/app/lib/library/file_a.rb
/app/lib/library/file_b.rb
/app/lib/library/file_c.rb
```

Then you need to apply the following naming convention for your class and modules:

```
# /app/lib/library/file_a.rb

Module Library::FileA
  # your code
end
```

Here is the explaination from the rails guide: https://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/autoloading_and_reloading_constants.html#project-structure

> In a Rails application file names have to match the constants they
> define, with directories acting as namespaces.
>
> For example, the file app/helpers/users_helper.rb should define
> UsersHelper and the file app/controllers/admin/payments_controller.rb
> should define Admin::PaymentsController.

NB: Even if that's not your question, you need to know that there is debate whether application specific libraries should go in the `app/lib` or `lib` directory.
If you opt for `lib`, you can keep loading your files with `require` or you can add the folder to the autoload path

Comment: Great answer! In my case they're defined as classes. Should I redefine everything as modules instead? The libraries define some class methods.

Comment: Also, where would I add the attributes for this module, so I can initialize them?